# ng-repeat + ng-change - AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I'm still learning AngularJs and I've run into a situation that I can't seem to find any answer for (though I have found lots of answers that touch on the subject...nothing quite like what I need).

I have the following ng-repeat with the ng-model inside of it. This is working fine:

```
<tr ng-repeat="option in orderLine.options">
   <td>
      <input ng-change="updateOptionsTotal(option.price)" ng-model="option.price" value="{{ option.price }}">
   </td>
</tr>
```

Outside of the ng-repeat, I have the following as well:

```
<input value="{[{ options.total }]}" disabled>
```

This line will simply be the TOTAL of all of the option.price in the ng-repeat.

However, when I go to make a change in the input inside of the ng-repeat...I don't know how to grab all of option.prices (as there could be many) and add them all up to create the new total. I have the updateOptionsTotal method in the $scope...but as of right now it's just blank as I'm not sure how to go about doing what I need done.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What does that template syntax do `{[{ value }]}`?

Comment: I'm using AngularJs with Laravel Blade...so {{ }} don't work, thus I changed the syntax for the Angular brackets. I thought I had removed them all from my code snip to not confuse anyone. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all prices and calculate new total, after that update the value of total with the new calculated result.

```
$scope.updateOptionsTotal = function(){
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.orderLine.options, function(value, key) {
        total = total + value.price;
    });
    $scope.options.total = total;   
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.